# Fan won't stop spinning

Tags: 18.04, fan

I have a clevo n141wu intel i5-8250U Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried lm-sensors and when sudo pwmconfig is executed it won't find my fan.

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +71.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +71.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +69.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +47.0°C  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +60.0°C  

$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
68000
59000
68000
47000
```

Is there any other way I can control my fan?

Comment: what does htop tell you about process utilization? something spinning your CPU at 100%? could it be the GPU heating up? Which graphics card are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this utility https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan, it's based on lm-sensors and it will manage the fan speed and log them.